# Creating/Updating products programatically in Magento

Tags: performance, magento, model, product

I've written a module to import products and I'm currently using Magento's product model to add/update products accordingly. However, this is proving to be very slow (possibly because I have the catalog index enabled?).

Even doing just

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->save();
```

Is incredibly slow - We're talking maybe 2 seconds per product (I'm doing 5 per http request, and using javascript to make several requests).

Each product needs to have some attributes updated, category ids changed, and the stock levels updated. At the moment, I'm looping through 20 products and it's taking near enough 60 seconds. In production, it will be looping through 200-300 products (although on a much more powerful server).

Is there a better/faster way of creating/updating the products? Obviously I could just use SQL but I don't fancy figuring out Magento's intense EAV database structure!

Sorry if this is a naff question, I'm not sure how best to word it!

Comment: have you tried MAGMI? it's the best tool for importing/updating products

Comment: Hadn't even heard of it to be honest, but I may well give it a go! This same import process will (it was originally going to, but it's been pulled for now) connect to Microsoft Dynamics MSSQL database and import the products from their on a cron job, so taking 10 minutes for 200 products isn't a viable option!

I'll look into this, thank you :)

Comment: Could you post more code? I've done the same thing, and my import process hasn't been slow.

Comment: No more code is necessary, I've commented out everything apart from loading and saving the product, it still takes just as long! The only other stuff is setting attributes (using $product->setDescription() for example).

I'll try turning off indexing, then importing, then turning it back on - hopefully that will improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the indexer mode to manual whilst importing will give you at least some performance gains. You can obviously set this in the admin area, but you can also do it via your script:

```
//Set to manual mode
$processCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
foreach($processCollection as $process) {
    $process
        ->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)
        ->save();
}

//Set back to real time mode
$processCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
foreach($processCollection as $process) {
    $process
        ->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
        ->save();
}
```

If you are looking for a way to reindex directly in your script after importing...

```
$processCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach($processCollection as $process) {
      $process
         ->reindexEverything();
}
```

But, **Magmi** - http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/ - is not only amazingly fast at importing products, but it also provides some really nice features.

I don' know of any other product import tool for Magento that is as fast (would be interested if anyone else knows of one that is as fast or faster?)

Comment: I shall give this a try, thank you very much! I'll report back whether or not it helped :)